# Form is not submitting in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-forms

I have a form that should print the data in console but unfortunately I'm not able to.
I want to print data to the console when a form is submitted.
The form is not submitting don't know why. I have the code below.
I would be very grateful if you could decide.

```
import { Button, Grid, Paper, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Page2(props) {
    const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const handelInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        console.log(name, value);
    };

    const handleData = (data) => {
        console.log("data");
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Paper
                style={{ margin: "10px auto", textAlign: "center" }}
                elevation={24}  >
                <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Todo Application</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleData)}>
                    <Grid
                        style={{ margin: "10px" }}
                        container
                        spacing={1}
                        direction="column"  >
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <TextField
                                name="title"
                                label="Title"
                                variant="standard"
                                onChange={handelInputChange} />
                            <TextField
                                name="desc"
                                label="Description"
                                variant="standard"
                                onChange={handelInputChange} />
                            <TextField
                                name="priority"
                                type="number"
                                label="Priority"
                                variant="standard"
                                onChange={handelInputChange} />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>    
                <button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                    Add
                </button>
            </Paper>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a bit of things to do in order to get this form to `console.log`. First, as the other poster mentioned, the submit `button` needs to be within the form (and you probably want to uppercase that `B` in "`<Button`" so that you're using the MUI component.

```
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleData)}>
            <Grid
              style={{ margin: "10px" }}
              container
              spacing={1}
              direction="column"
            >
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField
                  name="title"
                  label="Title"
                  variant="standard"
                  onChange={handelInputChange}
                />
                ...
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            // Moved and renamed here
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Add
            </Button>
          </form>
```

That solves your submit problem, but then you will notice that the `console.log("data")` will only ever contain an empty object `{}` -- this is because `react-form-hooks` needs to be given a `FormProvider` and made aware of the form elements in the form that it should control.  To do this you need to register the component. I have added [working code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicbuttons-material-demo-forked-l1bi8?file=/demo.js) on one way to complete this task.

In this example, I created a generic `FormFieldController` wrapper that you can use to pass in whatever just about form fields you need. (I would not use this in production code, without cleanup, as it is only meant as an example):

```
const FormFieldController = ({
  component: Component = TextField,
  name = "",
  defaultValue = "",
  label = "",
  validation = {},
  required = false,
  valueProp = "value",
  callbackProp = "onChange",
  onChange,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      rules={validation}
      render={({
        field: { onChange: internalOnChange, value, ref },
        fieldState: { error }
      }) => {
        const pipes = {
          [valueProp]: value,
          [callbackProp]: function () {
            internalOnChange.apply(this, arguments);

            // Middleman callback to allow for onChange back to the caller, if needed
            if (onChange) {
              onChange.apply(this, arguments);
            }
          }
        };
        return (
          <>
            <Component
              id={name}
              inputRef={ref}
              caption={error ? error?.message : ""}
              label={label}
              {...pipes}
              {...rest}
            />
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[Working CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicbuttons-material-demo-forked-l1bi8?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong HTML structure. `button[type=submit]` should be inside `<form>` tag

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steve, You can use simply register function to do the work for you just supply register function in the inputRef of your MUI Form Component.

```
import { Button, Grid, Paper, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Page2(props) {
    const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();

const handelInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(name, value);
};

const handleData = (data) => {
    console.log("data",data);
};

return (
    <>
        <Paper
            style={{ margin: "10px auto", textAlign: "center" }}
            elevation={24}  >
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Todo Application</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleData)}>
                <Grid
                    style={{ margin: "10px" }}
                    container
                    spacing={1}
                    direction="column"  >
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <TextField
                            name="title"
                            label="Title"
                            variant="standard"
                            inputRef={register} 
                            onChange={handelInputChange} />
                        <TextField
                            name="desc"
                            label="Description"
                            variant="standard"
                            inputRef={register}
                            onChange={handelInputChange} />
                        <TextField
                            name="priority"
                            type="number"
                            label="Priority"
                            variant="standard"
                            inputRef={register}
                            onChange={handelInputChange} />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            <button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                Add
            </button>
            </form>    
        </Paper>
    </>
);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to defer to this answer as mine is probably a bit too "over engineered" for the question. +1 for @pankaj -- I'll leave my answer for posterity. :D

Comment: Yes it is but that is still useful for some complex controlled components.